# How to know ajax methods are called in UIWebview

Tags: ajax, uiwebview, javascript-injection

I am working on app which is base on the MobileWebSite. I am handling few things on the app side based on the users interaction on the webSite. For this I have to detect the when the ajax methods are called. I am trying to inject a javascript in

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

to detect ajax calls. But I am unable to catch ajax calls after pageload. 
Please help if any one has done this.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `NSURLProtocol` to detect ajax calls :

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
{
    //Here you will catch all requests including ajax
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to send notification to the view controller form the custom protocol?